# How Do I Get Rid of Apps from Play Store Update List?

Tags: google-play-store

For the past few months, I have had the following items in my Play Store update list:

[image: Google Sheets and Google Slides "Updates" in Play Store]

I do not have these apps installed on my device. I do not *want* these apps installed on my device. Yet I do not see a way to get rid of them from this update list.

How can I get rid of these apps from my update list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of update notifications for a given app in Google Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58021/how-to-get-rid-of-update-notifications-for-a-given-app-in-google-play-store)

Comment: @Firelord: Two of the answers there cite a discontinued app that does not actually solve the problem, one requires root, and the last one requires you to install the app (then disable it). Thanks, though!

Comment: Seems like they must have at least been pre-installed if they're presenting updates, otherwise that would be fairly unusual. They don't appear in Settings → Apps → All?

Comment: No, neither are in Settings → Apps → All. FWIW, this is a Nexus 4 running stock Android 5.1.1. They are not listed in disabled apps either, though I have disabled Google Drive.

Comment: I think these apps were separated from the Google Drive app ([Source](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/04/30/google-releases-dedicated-docs-and-spreadsheet-apps-for-android-and-ios/), [Source 2](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/new-mobile-apps-for-docs-sheets-and.html)). I assume that because it previously included the functionality that these apps provide they somehow appear as updates.

Comment: @bmdixon I would agree but Google Drive is disabled in OP's device, and Play Store also knows which apps are disabled, so it seems odd that Play Store is still suggesting them when Drive is already disabled by owner of the device. // Though I would say, if nothing works (as non-root) then just download them and disable them, to get rid from update list at least.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to "Settings > Apps > Google Play" and then pressing the "Clear Data" button. Then go back into Google Play Store. You may have to sign in again but I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't installed the application than most probably its a System Application and cannot be removed permanently as the APK is stored under /system/app or /system/priv-app directory. It can only be disabled and whenever you factory reset the phone, the application will come up again.

You can try doing this:

Goto Settings>Apps>Select the App you want to remove > Disable(Assuming that you do not want to use this application)

And then check in Play Store, it will be removed.

Hope it helps.