# Possible to detach a system app from the Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, updates, system-apps

Is it possible to detach a system app from the Play Store, without disabling or uninstalling it?

I would prefer to leave the system app in its partition, and not move it.

Solution should be compatible with Android KitKat.  Solutions requiring root privileges *are* completely acceptable.

The device is rooted. I've already tried [using TiBu to detach apps from playstore](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110135/16575), but it didn't work (they don't get detached at all, so the scheduling won't help either; researching it online, it seems like it is a known problem with *Titanium Backup*, and has been for a long time).

Comment: @Izzy Now I have. :)  When I tried doing any detaching in *Titanium Backup*, it didn't have any effect.  Putting something that didn't have any effect on a repeated schedule seems like it will just have no effect more often! :)  But it does seem that it worked for Craig... curious... maybe because his test device was running Lollipop and mine was running KitKat... or maybe due to other Android ROM fragmentation differences.

Comment: I rather suspect "other" here (or it must have skipped Kitkat in "working"), as my last try definitely was pre-Kitkat. Without that schedule, apps stayed disconnected for me no longer than 24h. So maybe just try again? Or are you still on Kitkat?

Comment: To confirm TiBu doesn't work with kit kat . I had issues with Google play updates  with my previous phone and restored Nandroid with earlier version of Play and tried as hard as i could with TiBu, ROM Toolbox Pro, nothing worked ( updated within few hours ). Mr. Google didn't show an alternate way @izzy. Scheduling didn't help either