# How to stop update

Tags: application-autoupdate

There are some apps like Facebook that I don’t want to update. And frequently I see a notification in app and in Play Store for its update.

Please let me know how to get rid of update of some specific apps.

[image: Update Notification on Play Store]

[image]

I don't want to upgrade Facebook app but every time I see "upgrade" notification on Facebook app. Recently I did reset my device and before reset, I upgraded Facebook but after upgrade, some options were missing in app. That's why I don't want to upgrade it again.

Comment: Also see: [How to get rid of update notifications for a given app in Google Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/58021/16575)

Answer (score 0):

You could just go to Playstore and select the app you'd like to not auto update. When you click the 3 dots(overflow icon) at the top right uncheck auto update.

Apps nowadays though have started implementing a policy where you can't use the app if you haven't downloaded the update.

Comment: I already did this. There is no auto but I don't want to see the name of those apps that I don't want to update, under Updates. Apart from this, even in facebook app, I see update notification and it tries to force me to update facebook.