# Is there a way to hide an app from the Play Store without uninstalling it?

Tags: google-play-store

Is it possible to remove an app from the Play Store's "installed" list but keep it installed? I can't seem to find a workup on this.

Comment: This sounds like an A-B question... what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Detach it from the market. See if the answer here helps. https://android.stackexchange.com/q/58021/96277

Comment: @Firelord It still comes back after being detached

Comment: @endolith you can setup an automation app to periodically detach it.

Answer (score 2):

That is possible, but requires a rooted device. Some apps provide a feature to accomplish that, e.g.:

- [Hide Updates In Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whitedavidp.hideupdatesinplaystore)
- [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup)

Note that, even once achieved, Playstore refreshes those "links" – usually within ~24h. The first app takes care for that itself, and with *Titanium* you can setup a corresponding schedule to repeat the action (hint: use a filter, store the filter definition, and use that for the "scheduled task").

Answer (score 0):

yes you can but you just have to follow a simple step *WARNING* it will not show some other apps too... for example i want to hide a app that is for age group 12+ (this rating you can see after searching for that app and see the age recommendation)... so now you have to go in parental control in play store and then add a pin... now just select the age group below the one of 12 years and set it... now if you search for that app it would not show it 
(but now you wont be able to see other apps that of category 12+) however if you have downloaded that app it would show in updates section