# Detach app from market

Tags: google-play-store

Requesting updates on the fight of how to detach apps from Google Play

- Titanium Backup is temporary...

.

- Automatize a detachment with Tasker or anything else, is extremely verbose (and other things)

.

- Resigning the APK does not work always (actually, worked very few times).

. Sometimes it breaks the app

. Sometimes it still shows on the store

. It can never be applied to system apps (like good old google keyboard)

Comment: Have you seen [How to get rid of update notifications for a given app in Google Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/58021/16575) Does the TiBu approach described there (note the scheduler part) not work anymore? Nor any of the other approaches?

Comment: Thank you. Scheduling tasks help. Very close to the ideal. My only pain will be recreating all those schedules and filters every time I format the phone... since TiBu can't backup itself, forcing me to copy the data manually and keeping it somewhere

Comment: But I'm still looking for something better. By this method, it reattaches after a reboot. Plus, I have to create many schedules to cover all the times this thing resyncs

Comment: Even creating 5 schedules still don't cover the times. Apparently this resync is random. TiBu doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'll double check but seems that the jrummy root tools app has that feature. Anyone else tried it and can verify either way feel free. If not ill have access on my rooted phone soon and will update my answer then..

Comment: AFAIK it's the same as with TiBu: if you detach an app from play, it gets re-attached within ~24h usually. The latter is a task performed regulary by one of the Google apps (not sure if Playstore itself does that or some other part of the suite).